# List keeps getting reset to empty. How can I fix this?

Tags: c#

I'm currently learning C# and have assigned myself to make a program to help me understand OOP which essentially takes in values and assigns them to variables. The program takes in information about football players; the name, last name, position, and shirt number.

I'm trying to use getters and setters to ensure that a shirt number can only be used once. So i've set a list up that stores all the shirt numbers that are being used. The problem i'm having is: the list keeps getting reset and I have no idea why. After one value has been added, by the time the next one gets added, the list is empty again. This makes my if statement in the setter not work as the list does not contain any values.

Im sure this is a rookie error and should be shouting at me, but Im new to this language and am not really sure on all the ins and outs of it.

I haven't really tried much, and I cant find anything online as this seems to be a specific error that im having. I don't know enough about the language to properly troubleshoot this, and what I do know about the language tells me this should work.

```
namespace RandomObject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Player player1 = new Player("Lucas", "Torreira", "Defensive Midfielder", 11);
            Player player2 = new Player("Alexandre", "Lacazette", "Striker", 9);
            Player player3 = new Player("Pierre-Emerick", "Aubameyang", "Striker", 14);
            Player player4 = new Player();

            Console.Write("Please enter new players first name: ");
            player4.Name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Please enter new players last name: ");
            player4.LastName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Please enter new players position: ");
            player4.Position = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Please enter new players shirt number: ");
            player4.ShirtNo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            player1.PrintPlayerInfo();
            player2.PrintPlayerInfo();
            player3.PrintPlayerInfo();
            player4.PrintPlayerInfo(); 

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}  

class Player
    {
        private List<int> shirtNumbers = new List<int>();
        private int _shirtNo;

        public void PrintPlayerInfo() //<access modifier> <return type> <method name>(parameters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player: {0} {1}", Name, LastName);
            Console.WriteLine("Position: {0}", Position);
            Console.WriteLine("Shirt No.: {0}\n", _shirtNo);
        }


        public Player()
        {
            Name = string.Empty;
            LastName = string.Empty;
            Position = string.Empty;
            _shirtNo = 0; 
        }


        public Player(string name, string lastName, string position, int shirtNo)
        { 

            Name = name;
            LastName = lastName;
            Position = position;
            _shirtNo = shirtNo;

            AddToList(_shirtNo);

        }

        private void AddToList(int newNumber)
        {
            shirtNumbers.Add(newNumber);
            Console.WriteLine(shirtNumbers[0]);
        }


        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public int ShirtNo
        {
            get { return _shirtNo;  }
            set
            {

                if (shirtNumbers.Contains(value) == false)
                {

                    _shirtNo = value;

                }
                else
                {
                    _shirtNo = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my main method I declare 3 instances of the class, with shirt numbers 11, 9, and 14. So when it comes to inputting one into the console using readlines and such, if I were to enter 14, the shirt number should be set to 0. However if I enter 10, it should be set to 10.

Comment: You should have a static list of numbers. Otherwise every player has its onw list of valid numbers.

Comment: HimBromBeere, Oh my god that instantly fixed it. Could you explain why that fixed it? What does static change in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Player` class now does two things: it holds information about one player, and it contains a list of shirt numbers for all players. One of those two doesn't belong there.

The `private List<int> shirtNumbers = new List<int>();` is an instance variable, meaning each player has its own list of shirt numbers. So if you assign a shirt to player X, the list in player Y's instance has no notion of this, enabling you to assign shirt N to both player X and Y.

Sure, you could fix this by declaring the list to be static, but that's just bad design; the `Player` class needs to know about one player, not all of them.

So instead keep this shirt number check *outside* your player class. Declare the shirt list before the player list, and modify your code accordingly.

Comment: Ah okay. So I shouldn't be using classes to do things like that in the first place? Why is just declaring the list to be static bad design?

Comment: There's no reason not to use classes, but each player should not need to know about which shirt numbers have been used.  It's probably better that the code that instantiates each player knows that and assigns shirt numbers to players accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a static list of numbers. Otherwise every player has its own list of valid numbers.

```
class Player
{
    private static List<int> shirtNumbers = new List<int>();
    private int _shirtNo;
}
```

This way you have a single list that all your player share.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. So am I right in saying that in the code I had, I could have accessed each player's shirtNumbers list with player1.shirtNumber, player2.shirtNumber etc...? What does static actually do?

Comment: @ScottKinchlea It decouples a member from a certain instance. This way yur member doesn´t belong to a specific instance of your class, but to the class itself (and thus is shared between all instances of the class). However you don´t need an instance at all to access a static member. Have a look at its docs.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the AddToList method on your constructor to add the shirtlist number which is correctly but when you are defining ShirtNo setter you are not adding to the list
Fix :

```
    public int ShirtNo
    {
        get { return _shirtNo;  }
        set
        {

            if (shirtNumbers.Contains(value) == false)
            {

                _shirtNo = value;
                AddToList(value)
            }
            else
            {
                _shirtNo = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i copied your code to debug in my local machine. Few changes that needs to be done to your

1.The shirtNumbers list  has to be declared static , if not for every instance of player class will have List *(private static List shirtNumbers = new List();)*

2. You are assigning values to the variable directly and not to the property in both the constructors.(getter setter is called property in C#).Hence the if condition inside setter wont be called.

---

```
    class Player
    {
      private static List<int> shirtNumbers = new List<int>();
       private int _shirtNo;

    public void PrintPlayerInfo() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Player: {0} {1}", Name, LastName);
        Console.WriteLine("Position: {0}", Position);
        Console.WriteLine("Shirt No.: {0}\n", _shirtNo);
    }


    public Player()
    {
        Name = string.Empty;
        LastName = string.Empty;
        Position = string.Empty;
        ShirtNo = 0;  
    }


    public Player(string name, string lastName, string position, int shirtNo)
    {

        Name = name;
        LastName = lastName;
        Position = position;
        ShirtNo = shirtNo;

        AddToList(_shirtNo);

    }

    private void AddToList(int newNumber)
    {
        shirtNumbers.Add(newNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(shirtNumbers[0]);
    }


    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public int ShirtNo
    {
        get { return _shirtNo; }
        set
        {

            if (shirtNumbers.Contains(value) == false)
            {

                _shirtNo = value;

            }
            else
            {
                _shirtNo = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```